# Symfony 4 Simple Lifecycle Callbacks don't seem to be working

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine-orm, callback, symfony4

I have simple entity called Post.

```
/**
 * Class Post
 * @package App\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Blog\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *
 */
class Post
{ 
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"default":"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    protected $createdDateTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     */
    public function testEvent()
    {
        $this->createdDateTime = '2018-11-11';
        //dump(123); exit; this is not working either
    }
}
```

Now I am using Nelmio Alice Bundle to generate some database fixtures and when I am done with that I loop through them to persist what I have into the database.

```
foreach($this->fixtures as $fixture) {
    $this->entityManager->persist($fixture);
    if($counter === self::BATCH_SIZE['MEDIUM']) {
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->clear();
    }
    counter++;
}
```

As you can probably guess, nothing happens in terms of events. I think it's not being emitted for some reason.

What may be important - I am doing that from functional test level. Am I right in thinking that this is the reason why I can get that to work?

Comment: Isn't this because $this->createdDateTime = '2018-11-11' tries setting a string to a datetime field?

Comment: Are you looping through the fixtures after they have been already persisted? Or where does this loop take place?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber If the type was a problem that would moan about wrong type. This is just example in my original code I have: $this->createdDateTime = new \DateTime(); - anyhow it's not even executing that based on event. When I call persist() it should fire and error or go through but it is not even getting there

Comment: @Padam87 - nope Alice Nelmio Bundle doesn't persit anything. That's my job to do this(correct me if I am wrong). This loop takes place in my service for creating dummy data. I am generating entities/fixtures with mentioned bundle and then I am trying to persist them. It works when I hardcode some data in there because createdDateTime is not null anymore. However it doesn't want to use event.

Comment: P.S I am also generating fixtures long before I even inject and use EntityManager.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used the Alice bundle for a while, you're right. Are they saved in the DB and everything? Do you have a flush() at the end of your loop too? Other than that, everything seems right to me.

Comment: Does your code walk through your `if` statement? ( `if($counter === self::BATCH_SIZE['MEDIUM'])` ? Did you try to dump/die at this point?

Otherwise everything seems okay for me.

Comment: @Padam87 No worries. Yes, they are going into DB when data is correct. It was working already, however, I am trying to enhance the code by handling createdDateTime automatically in my tests. 

I am creating something based on Alice bundle that will make functional testing a lot easier. One of the things is the easy creation of fixtures and test databases for your tests.  

Might be that events are not handled in tests?

Comment: @baris1892 - this bit works fine. I get to the loop. I am able to save a record to the database when there's data. The problem is it's not there because event is not handled.

Comment: @Robert, you didn't happen to forget `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` ?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber - nope, this would error a lot sooner. This is not related to my problem at all I am afraid. The script works fine. The only problem is that field createdDateTime doesn't get populated because the setter that should be fired on dispatch of that certain event is not handled at all.

Comment: @Robert, can you try using your setter method `$this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));` instead of `$this->createdDateTime = '2018-11-11';` ? I assume you have created getters and setters.

Comment: I have getters and setters. Makes no difference though. I did try to put @ORM\PrePersist() on both. However, effectively they are doing the same thing - setting value of createdDateTime.

I do have what you proposed in my original setter. I think I am not explaining this properly. 

Problem is not in the type of data. Problem is in that the property is not being populated due to Symfony's failure in event handling. This causes filed to be null. 

Problem is with events and not with data.

Comment: @Robert, I see. Maybe also try a different event like `PreUpdate` to see if that does work to make sure it is about the event(type)? Otherwise I also don't understand...

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber no worries. I did try that as well. Didn't work. I think it's a bug. I think that because I have just created my own event subscriber and I am able to capture that even without any problems. I will post that workaround as The answer. Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem seems to be in the fact that Symfony is not catching and handling Doctrine's LifeCycle events correctly. It was supposed to call a method of my choice on PrePersist event - setter for $createdDateTime in this case.

I am running that in my functional test so maybe that is the issue here?
I do not think I have called persist() before, which would cause that problem.
My script also works as expected when correct data is provided.

I believe it's Symfony's fault because when I have created my own event subscriber for *PrePersist* event I was able to actually handle that event.

It's not a solution but workaround - create your own event listener or subscriber and take care of that there.